# Can I use a action to pass a value to a method parameter?

Tags: c#

I will try my best to explain what I am asking.

Imagine I have a Action in one class:

```
public Action Something;
```

And in another class I subscribe a method ot it with a parameter

```
private void Foo(int num)
{
    Debug.Log(num);
}

OneClass.Something += Foo;
```

So basically I want the parameter of Foo to be something that the OneClass Passes. Is that something that exists in C#?

Comment: `Foo` is not an `Action` it is an `Action<int>`.

Answer (score 3):

Is this what you are trying to do:

```
public class Bar
{
    public event Action<int> Something;

    protected void OnSomething(int arg)
    {
        Something?.Invoke(arg);
    }
}


class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        var bar = new Bar();

        bar.Something += Foo;
    }

    static void Foo(int x)
    {
        Debug.WriteLine(x);
    }
}
```

What I have above is an event `.Something` defined with an event handler of `Action<int>` function prototype. `Action<T>` represents methods of the form `void f(T item)`.

Then I subscribe to the event with `bar.Something += Foo`

Finally, I define the method `OnSomething()` in order to allow the class `Bar` to trigger the event when needed.

Comment: @KevinVanGestel (or John) please edit the question to clarify you are looking for list of listeners - because the correct answer to the question *as posted* is `public Action<int> Something; bar.Something = Foo;`

Comment: @KevinVanGestel - see an update to the code with `OnSomething()` which is used to trigger the event. Triggering must happen from within the class the defines the event always, and thus the method that triggers the event has the `protected` access modifier.